# Undefined reference to 'add' (external assembler function)

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

I have an example with 4 files: add_main.c, add.h, Makefile and add.s. When I run make command on terminal I get an error "add_main.c:11: undefined reference to 'add'". I checked out answers to similar problems but they didn't work for me.

I tried declaring function add in add_main.c with and without keyword extern and writing function name as _add. That didn't help.

make response:

```
user@ser:~/add$ make
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -mcpu=xscale -O0 -Wall -o add_main.o-c add_main.c
/tmp/cc3HUJRk.o: In function 'main':
/home/user/add/add_main.c:11: undefined reference to 'add'
collect2: error: ld return 1 exit satus
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'add_main.o' failed
make: *** [add_main.o] Error 1
```

```
//add.h
int add(int a, int b);
```

```
//add_main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "add.h"

extern int add(int a, int b); 
.............
```

```
//add.s
    .text
    .align  2
    .global add
    .type   add, %function
add:
    add r0, r0, r1
    bx lr
    .size   add, .-add
```

```
//Makefile
TARGET := add

OBJ := $(TARGET)_main.o $(TARGET).o

ASFLAGS = -mcpu=xscale -alh=$*.lis -L
CFLAGS = -mcpu=xscale -O0 -Wall
LDFLAGS = -g

CC := arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
AS := arm-linux-gnueabi-as

.PHONY: test all clean distclean

test:   all
    qemu-arm $(TARGET)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) *.o

distclean:  clean
    $(RM) *.lis *~

allhfiles := $(wildcard *.h)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o:    %.s
    $(AS) -g $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o:    %.c $(allhfiles)
    $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

%.s:    %.c $(allhfiles)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fomit-frame-pointer -o $@ -S $<
```

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55575225/edit) and provide full make output. I'd like to see what commands it is running. Note that `add.s` or `add.o` don't appear in your makefile at all, so no wonder it's not getting built. Maybe you wanted to add it to `OBJ` but forgot?

Comment: Oh I scrolled off the `TARGET=add`, sorry about that. Just ignore the last part then :) But still post make output please.

Comment: `#include "add.h"` and then `extern int add(int a, int b); ` You're redefining the function for no tangible gain.

Comment: Federico klez Culloca did I understand correctly ~~~#include "add.h"~~~ should be taken out from add_main.c? If I take it out and run make I get the same result.

Comment: @Eranto No! `#include "add.h"` is correct.  Declaring `add` again in `add_main.c` is what's superfluous.

Comment: However the redundant declarations of `add` have nothing to do with why the program won't link.

Comment: The `make` ouput indicates that your makefile is not at all doing what you intended, so I'm adding the [tag:makefile] tag.  It seems that this is now really a question about `make` instead of about C or assembly.

Comment: I added -c in Makefile like so `%.o: %.s $(AS) -g $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<` and commented out add declaration in add_main.c. But I still get error.

Comment: So does your assembler `add` function label need to have an underscore prefix as in `_add`?

Comment: @fuz: GNU `as` doesn't support a `-c` flag, so I don't think that such a flag ought to be in the `%.o : %.s` rule.  It would be possible to run the assembler by calling `$(CC) -c`, but that isn't what OP is doing.

Comment: @RichardChambers: As you can see from the `make` output, the build is not even trying to link in the object file for `add`, so that can't be the problem at this stage.

Comment: @ Richard Chambers No, `add` should not have a prefix _ (still I tried it).

Comment: You seem to be missing a space before the `-c` but in the makefile the space is apparently there. Verify that is a normal space and a normal dash and that you are running this exact makefile. The output is from the `%.o:    %.c $(allhfiles)` rule which is not supposed to do the linking but due to the missing space it is trying to and fails.

Comment: @Eranto Sorry, I was wrong about the `-c`.  I though for some reason that `AS` was just `cc`.

Comment: Someone suggested to run `export QEMU_LD_PREFIX=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi` before `make`. Not sure what it does but now everything works properly.

Comment: Everyone thank you vary much for help!

Comment: Please _copy/paste_ your output; I see typos ("exit satus"; a missing space before `-c`). That suggests more may be missing. Why is the link command not echoed?